# How to open Perl file handle to write data via sudo (or as another user)

Tags: perl, permissions, posix, sudo, filehandle

I'd like to write data to a file, but the file handle should be opened with access permissions for a specific user.

Thus, the following statement:

```
open (FH, "> $filename") or die "$@\n";
```

would allow writing to a file as that particular user.

Is there a way to do this within a Perl script, without the entire script being run with `sudo -u $username`?

Comment: Well to change Effective UID `$>` you need to be running as root, is your script running either setuid root or as the root user?

Answer (score 2):

There are two established ways. Stackers, you are invited to edit this answer to fill in the drawbacks for each.

Run the program with `sudo`. The first thing you do in the program is to open the files you need and keep the handles, and then immediately afterwards [drop the root privileges](http://p3rl.org/Proc%3a%3aUID#DESCRIPTION). Any further processing must take place with low privileges. The Apache httpd works likes this, it opens the log files as `root`, but continues running as `nobody` or similar.

If you don't like that way, run the program normally, and when you need to elevate, create a new process and have it run with a user configured `sudo`, `su -`, `kdesu`/`gksu` or whatnot. The CPAN client works likes this, it fetches, unpacks, builds and tests a module as a normal user, but calls `sudo make install` etc. when it's time to install.

Comment: I do not know if I can open a writable file handle that uses `sudo`. I'm really trying to avoid `sudo`, unless I can make that file handle writable for that user. As for the second option, I'd need to pass the `sudo`'ed program a Perl hash reference, somehow, which doesn't seem straightforward. Does this help the question make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to daxim's suggestions is to have the script owned by the specific user and have the script permissions include the setuid and/or setgid bits.

Comment: ...note, however, that this can be a royal pain to update/maintain long-term because most (if not all) *nices will clear the suid/sgid bits every time you edit the file.