# Open file in perl with sudo

Tags: perl, file-io, sudo

I'd like to write data to a file, but the file handle should be opened with sudo or else I get permission denied error. But looks like something like following is not possible in perl?

```
sudo open (FH, "> $filename") or die "$!\n";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open Perl file handle to write data via sudo (or as another user)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823665/how-to-open-perl-file-handle-to-write-data-via-sudo-or-as-another-user)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739653/perl-system-calls-when-running-as-another-user-using-sudo

Comment: The problem is similar to How to open Perl file handle to write data via sudo (or as another user), but I cannot run the script which is opening a file as sudo.

Comment: Then take a step back and help us understand what you actually mean to accomplish, and why that is not an adequate solution.

Comment: I am trying to open a file in a secure location from a perl script. The perl script cannot run as "sudo", so I am trying to elevate the user permissions in the perl script when it tries to open the file/write to file. What are the possible ways to do so?

Answer (score 5):

`sudo` is a linux command, it is not a Perl function. You can run the whole Perl script with sudo (`sudo perl script.pl`), or you can change your user id in Perl by assigning to `$<` and `$>` special variables (see [perlvar - Perl predefined variables](http://p3rl.org/perlvar)) which will only be possible with extra privileges, anyway.

BTW, `open` sets `$!` on failure, not `$@`.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(my $pipe_fh, '-|', 'sudo', 'cat', $filename) or die "Unable to open pipe: $!\n";
```

It creates another process to solve your problem that may be better solved by running the script with the correct rights.

Comment: Ok, so if i have to create a file when it doesnt exist or append to existing one, what should be the above command? My tried something like - my $table_mapping = '/opt/temp';
unless (-e $table_mapping) {
        open (my $TBLFILE, '-|', 'sudo', '>> $table_mapping') or die "Can't open '$table_mapping': $!\n";
        close $TBLFILE;
}

Comment: `-|` is to a pipe what `<` is to a file.  Conversely, `|-` allows you to write to a pipe, but if you need external programs to proxy so much of your IO, you *really* need to reexamine the rights under which you're running your script.  ... and no, the external command `sudo >> $table_mapping` probably won't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I got the reading from file right. However, writing a simple string to the file seems complicated. Can you give me an example of appending a line to a file? I am also trying to re examine user permission issue.

Comment: In the same way I've used `cat` above to read a file, you can probably abuse `tee` to write a file.  Of course it will have the side effect of also sending everything you write to STDOUT.  This way lies madness.....